# Pandas pivot table return string not value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame that is like

Data columns (total 4 columns):

```
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   cluster    26 non-null     object 
 1   WORK_DATE  26 non-null     object 
 2   tier       26 non-null     object 
 3   UNIT_SOLD  26 non-null     float64
```

And I am trying to `pivot_table` it to `index=["cluster"], columns=["WORK_DATE"]`, but return tier instead of `unit_sold`. Is there any way to make it work?

```
    cluster WORK_DATE   tier    UNIT_SOLD
--- ------- ---------   ----    ---------
0   Gen MerchA  April   tier_8  119356.0
1   Gen MerchA  May     tier_7  140698.0
2   Gen MerchB  April   tier_4  104370.0
3   Gen MerchB  May     tier_4  114600.0
4   Gen MerchC  April   tier_8  92484.0
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. `df.pivot_table(index='cluster', columns='WORK_DATE', values='tier', aggfunc='first')` ?

Comment: @HenryEcker. Thanks for editing my question. New to here. I have tried the code that you wrote, but it returns error DataError: No numeric types to aggregate. If i just have pivot_table(index='cluster', columns='WORK_DATE') then it returns the coordinate `unit_sold`. Does that make my question more clear?

Comment: A sample of the DataFrame content as well as the expected output would be helpful.